# Has flash player 10.1 been released so far?

Tags: flash, flashlite

I just read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907250/should-i-wait-for-flash-player-10-1-or-go-with-flash-lite-3-to-develop-flash-cont) which said **flash player 10.1** provides consistent runtime for desktop and mobile devices.

I just asked a question on porting a desktop application to mobile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084967/how-to-connect-to-and-play-fms-stream-with-flash-lite-on-mobile-phones), but if **flash player 10.1** is available I won't bother to do the porting stuff.

**UPDATE**

Can someone give a link where mentions about the **consistent runtime for desktop and mobile** ?

Comment: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/
Pre-release only.

Comment: The full release is available, it's not prerelease anymore. They launched it officially last week. See Wind Chimez's comment.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, i think it's there.
Check here.
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Adobe is providing it for download.

Comment: Yes, it has been released after 7 release candidates making it probably the most solid release of Flash Player ever. Especially considering the variety of platforms it aims for.

Comment: Can you give a link where mentions about the **consistent runtime for desktop and mobile** ?

Comment: @Ain I'm not sure how you got the correlation between there being 7 RCs and it being the most solid release ever?

Comment: @Rowland Not only that FP10.1 is on for almost any mobile device except iDevice, AIR for Android is awaiting launch, it's optimised like never before and I've benchmarked it at about 30% off FP 10's CPU load in my own apps. Safari alone crashed twice a day with Flash Player 10. Hasn't done so since 10.1 stable. Correlation is there since it took a huge release delay and several candidates to reach where it is. If you take a look at the pace in Adobe's Bug System, you get the picture.

Comment: Which smartphones actually support it then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It has been released for Desktop and Mobile.

Here is a link to the Adobe Mobile Development Center: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/index.html?navID=gettingstarted

Comment: Did you find anywhere about the consistent runtime for desktop and mobile ?

Comment: See my new answer. The system would not let me add another link to my first answer due to lack of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The release notes do mention a consistent browser based runtime.

> The consistent Flash Player browser-based runtime is the most productive way to deliver content to users across operating systems and devices. Runtime consistency helps reduce the cost of creating, testing and deploying content across different device, software, network, and user contexts, and helps improve business results.
>   http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/838/cpsid_83808.html#new%20platforms